# added gem and got this error undefined method `acts_as_votable' for #<Class:0x00007f65df881b38>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

baby Ruby coder here.

I followed the steps here:https://masteruby.github.io/weekly-rails/2014/08/05/how-to-add-voting-to-rails-app.html#.XMFebOhKg2w to upload this act_as_votable gem however when I refresh my site to see if it works I get the following error: `` undefined method `acts_as_votable' for #<Class:0x00007f65df881b38> ``

The code does not seem to like the fact that I have put `act_as_votable` in my model I would like to use it on.

The error in my console also indicates that something is wrong in my controller. Do I need to define something there too?

Thanks in advance,

Angela

Model I want to use the act_as_votable gem on, you can see i have added it as the instructions instructed:

```
class Hairstyle < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :user, optional: true
     has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
     validates :name, presence: true
     validates :description, presence: true
     validates :category, presence: true
     acts_as_votable 
     mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
   end
```

My hairstyles controller with the 'upvote' method at the end:

```
class HairstylesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:category].present?    
      @hairstyles = Hairstyle.where(category: params[:category])
    elsif params[:search].present?
      @hairstyles = Hairstyle.where('name ILIKE ?', '%#{params[:search]}%')
    else
      @hairstyles = Hairstyle.all
    end
  end

  def show
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new  
  end

  def new
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.new
  end

  def create
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.create(hairstyle_params)   
    @hairstyle.user = current_user
    if @hairstyle.save!
      redirect_to hairstyle_path(@hairstyle)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @hairstyle.update(hairstyle_params)
    redirect_to hairstyles_path
  end

  def destroy
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @hairstyle.destroy
    redirect_to hairstyles_path
  end

  def upvote
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:id])
    @hairstyle.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to hairstyles_path
  end

  private

  def hairstyle_params
    params.require(:hairstyle).permit(:name, :description, :category, :location, :stylist, :photo, :video_url, :photo_cache)
  end
end
```

My index file i'd like to display the gem on:

```
  <% @hairstyles.each do |hairstyle| %>
    <%= link_to "upvote", like_hairstyle_path(hairstyle), method: :put%>
  <%end %>
</div>
```

Here is my repo if needed :https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do

Comment: The example you posted in your question shows `acts_as_votable`, but your repo uses `acts_as_votable :hairstyle`. I don't see the syntax of passing a symbol (`:hairstyle`) to acts_as_votable. Can you confirm that's not a typo/error (in your code?)

Comment: Hi sorry I was just testing in my repo and I pushed it to see if it would make any difference - it didn't. I have reverted my code to how it is above, if this helps. I am not sure what I have done wrong. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't run all 4 setup steps:

> add 'acts_as_votable' to gemfile

Then run from terminal:

```
bundle install

rails generate acts_as_votable:migration

rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Hello, I did run the migration and bundle too. I can see that there has been a table created in my Schema with the heading "votes" . The migration has also been executed so I am not sure what is happening. Any thoughts. Do you need to see any other files? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I cloned & setup your repo & I saw a few things going on that might be the cause:

- The original error I got in this clone was due to `act_as_taggable` on your models. Your models should be annotated as `acts_as_taggable` (plural)
- When I was initially testing, I wasn't logged in. This silently fails, which makes it seem like upvote isn't work. You might want to disable those hearts unless a user is logged in
- Your html/erb template has some commented out code and such. This might be causing the link/URL to get swallowed and be non-clickable. I resolved it by deleting all styling & formatting except the link I was testing. I like using [Haml](http://haml.info/) to help reduce these kinds of nesting errors
- I didn't run into your class error, but I would suggest running `spring stop` and trying to start your server again (I disable spring on all of my rails projects)

Comment: Hi Jay I stripped everything back in my index.erb file and got rid of the commented parts. Once I had tidied it up and got rid of the extra code it seemed to work. I also made the mistake of not being logged in too once I had edited the code in the index.html.erb file this is why it was not working. Now it does Thank you!!!